# Measure signal strength of multiple access points in android

Tags: android-wifi

Hi i am developing an indoor positioning app. I am trying the method of **wifi fingerprinting** to  mark locations, I need to know a way to measure the signal strength of more than 1 Access point in less delay, I tried scanning the with `wifi.startscan` but its to slow , Can some one suggest me some other way to accomplish the task ?